# Problems with using glm in foreach

Tags: r, foreach, glm

I am trying to fun multiple glms using a foreach loop. The problem I am getting is when I try to specify weights in which it says that an object wasn't found. Below is code which reproduces the problem I'm having.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

registerDoParallel(cores=4)  
getDoParWorkers()



train_samples<-vector(mode="list", length=4)
for(i in 1:4){
  train_samples[[i]]<-sample(nrow(mtcars),nrow(mtcars)*.8,replace=FALSE)
}

train_samples
d_data<-mtcars
#Add a weights column to illustrate the issue. The actual weights would vary.
d_data$weights = 1 

#This results in an error: object 'd_data' not found
foreach(k=1:4) %dopar%{
  model.fit<-glm(formula='hp~cyl+disp+mpg',
                 family=poisson,
                 data=d_data[train_samples[[k]],],
                 weights=d_data[train_samples[[k]],12])
}

#Removing the weights condition makes it run fine.
foreach(k=1:4) %dopar%{
  model.fit<-glm(formula='hp~cyl+disp+mpg',
                 family=poisson,
                 data=d_data[train_samples[[k]],])
}
```

I have looked for a solution to this online, but haven't been able to find anything. I want to know why this is an issue and how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: I've added an additional example below.

```
w1<-numeric(25)+1

#This has the same problem with object w1 not being found.
#Setting .export="w1" doesn't help either
foreach(k=1:4, .export="w1") %dopar%{
  model.fit<-glm(formula='hp~cyl+disp+mpg',
                 family=poisson,
                 data=d_data[train_samples[[k]],],
                 weights=w1)
}

#However, manually defining a numeric vector for weights works
foreach(k=1:4) %dopar%{
  model.fit<-glm(formula='hp~cyl+disp+mpg',
                 family=poisson,
                 data=d_data[train_samples[[k]],],
                 weights=numeric(25)+1)
}
```

Edit 2: Version information.

Windows 10
RStudio version:    1.0.136
R version:          3.3.1
foreach version:    1.4.3
doParallel version: 1.0.10

Comment: you likely need to pass the weights/data to the core processing it. http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/
have you tried .export?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your error. I get a different error, "task 1 failed - "object 'k' not found".

Comment: @MJH, I've tried using .export="d_data" and get the same error with the warning that d_data is already being exported. I've added an additional example below.

Comment: @msubbaiah, I'm not sure why you're getting that error. I've added an additional example which might work for you if the error is caused by the 'weights' argument.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for the edit. The export function should work. I'm still not able to replicate your error. Both foreach loops ran for me.

Comment: @Kyle apologies for the delay. I haven't been able to run your example yet, but you could try manually defining a vector of weights the same length as your data and export that with the data using c(). In my experience, the error you're getting usually is because something that your code needs to run it's being delivered to the core that's processing the job. I'll run your example when I get to a computer and see if I can replicate your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate your error. I'm not sure why it was coming up, but I came up with a solution that worked.

If you take your glm function out of the loop and make a separate function, and then use that within the the loop it works.

```
model <- function(k, input_data, samples){

  samples <- samples[[k]]
  input_data <- input_data[samples,]
  weights <- input_data[samples, 12]
  print(weights)

  model.fit <- glm(formula = 'hp ~ cyl + disp + mpg',
                 family = poisson,
                 data = input_data,
                 weights = weights)

  return(model.fit)
}


trial.data <- foreach(k = 1:4, 
                      .errorhandling = 'pass') %dopar% {
                        model(k, d_data, train_samples)
                      }

print(trial.data)
```

Also, if you use `.errorhandling` it will give you more information, which sometimes can be useful (it wasn't in this case, but just fyi).

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, this doen't work quite right for me. It will run fine, but including the .errorhandling = 'pass'  causes the trial.data variable to be filled with the error messages. Does it store the error messages or the results when you run the code?

Comment: @Kyle apologies for the delay. I adjusted the model function. This works in parallel and non-parallel processing now. Also, you may want to investigate your sampling or weights before implementing this over many loops. If you switch to %do% from %dopar%, you do get NA values being reported with the print weights statement

Comment: Awesome, that works for me! I'm not sure why weights needs to be specified that specific way. I found out that if you use the speedglm package you don't run into the issue with defining weights. I think the NA values being reported with the print weights statement are arising due to defining the weights after sampling input_data. Switching input_data <- ... with weights <- ... fixes the problems with NA values. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this party, but the problem is that `glm()` is looking for weights first in the environment of data then the formula. Your supplied vector of weights doesn't appear in those environments when you run in parallel using `%dopar%`. Referencing the global environment allows the code to run correctly:

```
foreach(k=1:4) %dopar% {
  #Create a weight vector, saves on globalenv() references later
  w=d_data[train_samples[[k]],12]
  model.fit<-glm(formula='hp~cyl+disp+mpg',
                 family=poisson,
                 data=d_data[train_samples[[k]],],
                 #Instruct glm() to look in the global environment for weights
                 weights=globalenv()$w)
}
```